# App Center build fails error XALNK7000 Failed to resolve AndroidX.AppCompat.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableWrapper

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, appcenter

I am trying to build my Android (Xamarin.Forms) app on App Center. I can build and deploy it on a simulator but on App Center I get the error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5):
> error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:
> 'System.Void
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ShellSearchView/ClipDrawableWrapper::.ctor(Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable)'
> in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll' --->
> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
> AndroidX.AppCompat.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableWrapper
> [/Users/runner/work/1/s/EchoMessager.Android/MyApp.Android.csproj]
>
> Error: The process
> '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_12_24/bin/msbuild'
> failed with exit code 1

I set the SDK version to the latest stable (Xamarin.Android 13.2)

Comment: After updating Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials it works. The branch that was being built on App Center was not the same as the branch I was using on my dev environment so that's why I was able to build and deploy on my simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials it works. The branch that was being built on App Center was not the same as the branch I was using on my dev environment so that's why I was able to build and deploy on my simulator.